# How to include unsigned and aligned apk using gradlew assembleRelease?

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'm using `./gradlew assembleRelease` and it's generating a release.apk and unaligned.apk.

My question is how can I include an aligned apk without a signature to the output?

Comment: The aligned apk is the release.apk.

Comment: @JaredBurrows yeah but it's also signed. I want unsigned and aligned... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Gradle:

Actually, I just cloned the Android source code for the build tools: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/tasks/ZipAlign.groovy

```
// ----- PUBLIC TASK API -----
@OutputFile
File outputFile

@InputFile
File inputFile
```

A task **does** exist called: **ZipAlign**.

Have not tested this:

```
task alignAPK(dependsOn: assemble, type: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ZipAlign) {
    outputFile = file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/${project.name}-aligned.apk")
    inputFile = file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/${project.name}-unaligned.apk")
}
```

### Manually:

You are going to have to do it **manually**:

```
zipalign -v 4 unaligned.apk aligned.apk
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid that since I'm building a completely automated  setup. I could write a script to run gradlew and then run the zip align but I feel there is one option hidden to easily do the align.

Comment: @Jona I found the task in the source and wrote this for you.

Comment: Hey @Jared Burrows, that's awesome! Thanks for looking into that. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hey I did and seems like gradel can't find it. "Error:(100, 0) Could not find property 'ZipAlign' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@786e7001."

Comment: @Jona I specified the absolute path for the type and I added " quotes for the file paths. Try it now. gradlew alignAPK

Comment: Oops! Sorry was very busy and completely forgot! :) Credit give! Thanks for the awesome help!